# Getting rid of certain HTML tags

Tags: python, beginner, strings, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This code simply returns a small section of HTML code and then gets rid of all tags except for break tags.

It seems inefficient because you cannot search and replace with a beautiful soup object as you can with a Python string, so I was forced to switch it back and forth from a beautiful soup object to a string several times so I could use string functions and beautiful soup functions.  It seems that there must be a simpler way to do this without switching back and forth between soup objects and strings.

```
def whiteScrape(webaddress):
     url = (webaddress)
     ourUrl = opener.open(url).read()

     soup = BeautifulSoup(ourUrl)
     soup = soup.find("div", { "class" : "addy" })
     #below code will delete tags except /br
     soup = str(soup)
     soup = soup.replace('<br/>' , '^')
     soup = BeautifulSoup(soup)
     soup = (soup.get_text())
     soup = str(soup)
     soup=soup.replace('^' , '<br/>')

     return soup
```

The original HTML is something like:

```html
<div class = "addy"> <p> blah blah <br/> blahblah <br/> blah </p></div>
```

The output should be:

> ```html
> blah blah <br/> blahblah <br/> blah
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), `whiteScrape()` should be renamed to `white_scrape()`.

Variable names should be purposeful.  Therefore, it's a bad idea to continually redefine `soup`.  If someone were to ask you to explain what the variable `soup` contained, you would have a hard time explaining.

It seems like what you want to do is to stringify the children of div(s) in question.  One way to do that would be:

```
def white_scrape(url):
    page = opener.open(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    addr = soup.find('div', { 'class': 'addy' })
    return ''.join(str(child) for child in addr.children)
```

Note that this is not exactly equivalent to your original code.  For example, if an address contains an element, such as `123 1<sup>st</sup> St.`, this solution would preserve the `<sup>` tag and its contents, whereas your original code would discard the tag but keep its contents and strip the tag.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try to remember to use the underscore as a separator in the future, wasn't aware of that. I think the second part of your answer is leading me in the right direction however, it still returns some unwanted tags. The output is <p> blah <br/> blah <br/> blah </p> . The original HTML was just a div containing that <p> and its contents. I don't want to output the <p> tags. Obviously I could figure some workaround but I feel like I must be missing something in BeautifulSoup. I would think that i could output child of child but I can't get that to work as of yet.

Comment: Why don't you edit your question to state what HTML input you want to be able to handle, and what you expect the output to look like?